# UILocalNotification with vibration

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

Is there any way to add the vibration effect with local notification, while notification is triggered.

```
let AlarmNotification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    AlarmNotification.alertBody = title
    AlarmNotification.alertAction = "Open App"
    AlarmNotification.category = "AlarmCategory"

    AlarmNotification.soundName = soundName + ".mp3"
    AlarmNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(AlarmNotification)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the guidelines, you can only set Sounds as alert

> the system displays the alert message, badges the app, and plays a
>   sound—whatever is specified in the notification.

Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/